# eslint array-callback-return is invalid value warn is the wrong type

Tags: webpack, eslint

I created a SPA using create-react-app (https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/07/22/create-apps-with-no-configuration.html) without any problem

I then launched ATOM and start editing code, and found that eslint came up with the error:

```
Configuration for rule "array-callback-return" is invalid: value "warn" is the wrong type
```

so I opened `eslint.js` and located this line

```
'array-callback-return': 'warn'
```

which also seems correct to me.

is there any other error that I missed to check? or module that I need to update?

update: here's the error log

```
Error: /Users/Jim/Project/tomorrow/config/eslint.js:
Configuration for rule "array-callback-return" is invalid:
Value "warn" is the wrong type.
Referenced from: /Users/Jim/Project/tomorrow/package.json
at validateRuleOptions (/Users/Jim/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.0/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/config-validator.js:98:15)
at /Users/Jim/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.0/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/config-validator.js:144:13
at Array.forEach (native)
at Object.validate (/Users/Jim/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.0/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/config-validator.js:143:35)
at loadConfig (/Users/Jim/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.0/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/config.js:179:19)
at /Users/Jim/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.0/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/config.js:207:46
at Array.reduceRight (native)
at loadConfig (/Users/Jim/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.0/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/config.js:191:36)
at getLocalConfig (/Users/Jim/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.0/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/config.js:321:23)
at Config.getConfig (/Users/Jim/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.0/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/config.js:416:22)
```

my atom uses linter-eslint packages and I'm suspecting some settings could be the cause

Comment: interesting.. does changing that to 'error' instead of 'warn' throw the same message?

Comment: What is the version of `eslint` that you have (globally) installed? Type this into a terminal: `eslint --version`.

Comment: 1.7.3, it says... seems too old for me

Comment: Yes, it's a very old version and is likely the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see from the comments that you're using ESLint v1.7.3. [array-callback-return](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/array-callback-return) was added in [v2.0.0-alpha-1](http://eslint.org/blog/2015/12/eslint-v2.0.0-alpha-1-released#new-rules), and [string severity levels](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/commit/70e3a0297537eb1d84a0bf5cf764c01a792191fc) ("off"/"warn"/"error") were added in [v2.3.0](http://eslint.org/blog/2016/03/eslint-v2.3.0-released#support-for-string-severity-in-configs). Upgrading to at least v2.3.0 should fix the issue.

Comment: @alparslanahmed what is the output of `which eslint && eslint --version`?

Comment: /usr/local/bin/eslint v3.3.1

Comment: You might be using some editor plugin that ships with an outdated version of ESLint. Make sure your plugin has an option to use global ESLint: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/template/README.md#displaying-lint-output-in-the-editor.